# Vuetify conditional color parameter on element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using vuetify and it comes with an inbuilt color parameter and some predefined colors. I am dynamically loading data to components and I want the color of the component to be dependent on the datas value, eg. `complete: true, then color = green`

example of what I'm trying to do

```
<component :color="'deep-purple accent-4' if item.complete else 'grey'" v-for="n in items"></component>
```

The above example is rough and not legitimate code but I think highlights what I want to do. I know I could create my own classes and use the conditional class method but if possible Id like to stick with inbuilt Vuetify stuff

Comment: you could use computed property

Comment: @depperm I tried but you apparently can't pass a parameter into a computed function? I did try returning back the color via compute, going to try a method now but I don't think it will auto update dynamically if the item value changes.

Comment: Never mind a method did work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from using a method like you already posted in your answer, you could also do it inline with a ternary-operator.

```html
<component :color="n.complete ? 'green' : 'grey'" v-for="n in items"></component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a method to conditionally return the required value

```
<component :color="color(n.complete)" v-for="n in items"></component>
```

then created a new method

```
color: function(complete) {
    if (complete) {
        return 'green'
    } else {
        return 'grey'
    }
}
```